# Analytical Cross-Correlation between two time lagged Sinc functions gives complicated result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, correlation

I'm trying to calculate the analytical Cross-Correlation between two time-lagged Sinc functions, i.e.,

\begin{align} R(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \overline{\textrm{sinc}\left(\pi f \left(t - d_1\right)\right)} \cdot \textrm{sinc}\left(\pi f \left(t + \tau - d_2\right)\right) dt \end{align}

I already calculated this by hand and I should get:

\begin{equation} R(\tau) = \frac{\textrm{sinc}\left(\pi f\left(d_2 - d_1 - \tau \right)\right)}{f} \end{equation}

However, when I try to compute this in Mathematica using:

```
Integrate[Conjugate[Sinc[Pi*f*(t - d1)]] * Sinc[Pi*f*(t + \[Tau] - d2)], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {{f, t, \[Tau], d1, d2} \[Element] Reals, f >= 0, {d1, d2} >= 0}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

I get the following complicated answer:

```
(1/(4 f^2 \[Pi]^(5/2) (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])))(2 I \[Pi]^(3/2) Cos[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] - 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Cos[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] CosIntegral[2 d1 f \[Pi]] + 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Cos[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] CosIntegral[2 f \[Pi] (d2 - \[Tau])] - 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Cos[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] CosIntegral[2 f \[Pi] (-d2 + \[Tau])] + 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Cos[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] Log[1/(d2 - \[Tau])] - 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Cos[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] Log[1/(-d2 + \[Tau])] - Cos[f \[Pi] (d1 + d2 - \[Tau])] MeijerG[{{1/2, 1, 1}, {}}, {{1}, {}}, -(1/(d1 f \[Pi])), 1/2] - MeijerG[{{1/2, 1/2, 1}, {}}, {{1/2}, {}}, -(1/(d1 f \[Pi])), 1/2] Sin[f \[Pi] (d1 + d2 - \[Tau])] + 3 \[Pi]^(3/2) Sin[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] - 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sin[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] SinIntegral[2 d1 f \[Pi]] - 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sin[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] SinIntegral[2 f \[Pi] (d2 - \[Tau])] - 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sin[f \[Pi] (d1 - d2 + \[Tau])] SinIntegral[2 f \[Pi] (-d2 + \[Tau])])
```

which is obviously not what I want.

The weird thing is, when trying to calculate this Cross-Correlation with only one time-lagged Sinc function in Mathematica,

```
Integrate[Conjugate[Sinc[Pi*f*t]] * Sinc[Pi*f*(t + \[Tau] - d2)], {t, -Infinity,Infinity}, Assumptions -> {{f, t, \[Tau], d2} \[Element] Reals, f >= 0, d2 >= 0}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

it shows the correct result:

\begin{equation} R(\tau) = \frac{\text{sinc}(\pi  f (\text{d2}-\tau ))}{f} \end{equation}

How can I make sure that Mathematica always simplifies the answer? The command `Simplify[]` doesn't work in this case.

---

EDIT:

Interesting to note: when I omit the `GenerateConditions -> False` from the Mathematica query, I get the correct result but with additional (weird) conditions added to the solution. The Mathematica query:

```
Integrate[Conjugate[Sinc[Pi*f*(t - d1)]] * Sinc[Pi*f*(t + \[Tau] - d2)], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {{f, t, \[Tau], d1, d2} \[Element] Reals, f >= 0, {d1, d2} >= 0}]
```

computes to:

\begin{equation}
R(\tau) = \frac{\textrm{sinc}\left(f \pi \left(d_1 - d_2 + \tau \right)\right)}{f}, \textrm{ if } d_2 < \tau \textrm{ and } d_1 f \leq 0 \textrm{ and } \tau > 0
\end{equation}

How can I get this result without the (wrong) assumptions?

Comment: I wonder if it's a branch cut problem. I'm suspicious of the `Log`s in the computed answer. indeed, setting `f = 1; d2 = 1; d1 = 1; \[Tau] = 2` then evaluating the computed result numerically with `N` gives a number with possibly zero real part and definitely nonzero imaginary part (which is approximately $\frac{1}{2\pi}i$); however, re-computing the integral `Integrate[Conjugate[Sinc[Pi*f*(t - d1)]] * Sinc[Pi*f*(t + \[Tau] - d2)], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` with the constants defined gives `0`.

Comment: With assumptions, no problem: `Assuming[f>0 && τ>0, Integrate[Sinc[π*f*t]*Sinc[π*f*(t+τ)], {t, -∞, ∞}]]` gives `Sinc[f*π*τ]/f`.

Comment: @Roman, yes indeed. Although, in this case, it doesn't make sense to constrain $\tau$ to be a strictly positive value. This is an assumption I would like to avoid.